# How to trigger a pipeline when new branch is created

Tags: azure, azure-devops, git-branch, branching-and-merging

My requirement is I have to create a branch policy when ever a new branch is created through automation.
I have the Az cli script and Azure devops pipeline to apply for the new branch which.

How to dynamically take the new branch name and automatically has to trigger the pipeline to apply the policy on the branch? Please suggest me. I am using Azure devops, Azure repo.

Answer (score 1):

> How to dynamically take the new branch name and automatically has to
> trigger the pipeline to apply the policy on the branch?

If you are using yaml pipeline, you can [set trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger) to the new branch name in the `azure-pipelines.yml` file, so that the pipeline will be triggered automatically when the branch is created.

```
trigger:
- dev
```

Then in the pipeline, you can through `Build.SourceBranchName` predefined variable to get branch name.

[Build.SourceBranchName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml): The name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.

Comment: Is there any way in classic pipeline. Also I need to get the latest created branch name. How i can get that?